# VS 2015 Crash on Windows 10 Anniversary Update

Tags: c#, crash, windows-10

Recently I updated my Windows 10 with the Anniversary update. Since then Visual Studio crashes like crazy and some of the programs are not working.
Here are the crash errors:

```
        - <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    - <System>
      <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" /> 
      <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID> 
      <Level>2</Level> 
      <Task>0</Task> 
      <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-08-18T18:16:39.081375400Z" /> 
      <EventRecordID>2999</EventRecordID> 
      <Channel>Application</Channel> 
      <Computer>PC</Computer> 
      <Security /> 
      </System>
    - <EventData>
      <Data>Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.TypeLoadException at
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.VIL.DebuggerHost.VirtualAppDomain.get_DebuggerTypeUniverse() at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.VIL.DebuggerHost.GlobalContext.Dispose(Boolean) at
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.VIL.VisualStudioHost.VSGlobalContext.Dispose(Boolean) at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.VIL.VisualStudioHost.Interpreter.Destroy() at
 VSDebugEngine.ClrInspector.VilHelper.Dispose() at
 VSDebugEngine.ClrInspector.VilHelper.OnClose() at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DkmDataItem.InvokeOnClose(XapiComponentInfo*, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DkmDataItem) at
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DkmDataContainer.OnCloseNativeObject(XapiComponentInfo**) at
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DkmDataContainer.Callback_OnCloseNativeObject(IntPtr, XapiComponentInfo**)</Data> 
      </EventData>
      </Event>
```

---

And

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-08-18T18:16:39.250653400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>3000</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>PC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>devenv.exe</Data> 
  <Data>14.0.25420.1</Data> 
  <Data>57685d85</Data> 
  <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data> 
  <Data>10.0.14393.0</Data> 
  <Data>57898e34</Data> 
  <Data>e0434352</Data> 
  <Data>000d96c2</Data> 
  <Data>1e38</Data> 
  <Data>01d1f97c98f42dde</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</Data> 
  <Data>C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data> 
  <Data>f9cb238c-e79f-46c2-bd5e-1ddcaa9fb9c7</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  </EventData>
```

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-08-18T19:10:34.635049600Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>3122</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>PC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer.dll</Data> 
  <Data>14.0.23107.0</Data> 
  <Data>559b78f2</Data> 
  <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data> 
  <Data>10.0.14393.0</Data> 
  <Data>57898e34</Data> 
  <Data>e0434352</Data> 
  <Data>000d96c2</Data> 
  <Data>19cc</Data> 
  <Data>01d1f9843068d6aa</Data> 
  <Data>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer\v4.0_14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer.dll</Data> 
  <Data>C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data> 
  <Data>7d4ce7e2-ade2-4814-bb3e-84dfebb60b4e</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

---

```
    - <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    - <System>
      <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" /> 
      <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID> 
      <Level>2</Level> 
      <Task>0</Task> 
      <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-08-18T19:10:34.561501300Z" /> 
      <EventRecordID>3121</EventRecordID> 
      <Channel>Application</Channel> 
      <Computer>PC</Computer> 
      <Security /> 
      </System>
    - <EventData>
      <Data>Application: Microsoft.Alm.Shared.Remoting.RemoteContainer.dll Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException at
 System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited) at 
System.Diagnostics.Process.OpenProcessHandle(Int32 access) at
 System.Diagnostics.Process.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value) at 
Microsoft.Alm.Remoting.RemoteContainer.ServerHost.Execute(String clientObjectUri, Process parentProcess) at 
Microsoft.Alm.Remoting.RemoteContainer.EntryPoint.ExecuteInOtherAppDomain(String clientObjectUri, Int32 parentProcessId) at 
Microsoft.Alm.Remoting.RemoteContainer+EntryPoint.ExecuteInOtherAppDomain(System.String, Int32) at 
Microsoft.Alm.Remoting.RemoteContainer+EntryPoint.Main(System.String[])</Data> 
      </EventData>
      </Event>
```

I have a simple Windows Forms App. It was working alright before the update. Now it's not working. It starts as process but nothing more. No UI shows up. When I open the solution and choose some cs or designer files a loading message box shows saying "Opening the file..." and loads endlessly.

I have another simple launcher for the Mail App.

```
public static void Main()
{
      Process.Start("explorer", @"shell:Appsfolder\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.mail");
}
```

It's not working any more. O_o If I type the shell *explorer shell:Appsfolder\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.mail* through Run it is working fine though. What have they done to the new Windows?

Comment: The joys of love to live in the bleeding edge, either do a system backup or think twice before installing such update on a system you use daily for work :)

Comment: Don't worry. I always do a complete system backup before update. I can go back to the working version whenever I want. But now I want to know how to fix these problems.